# Smilies in form are saved as ???? in database

Tags: django, django-forms, mariadb

In my Django app and MariaDB database, when users post form containing smilies like  the smiley is saved as `????` which is clearly not intended.

The function in the views:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def send_letter(request):
    args = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SendLetterForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():           
            d = form.save(commit = False)
            try:
                author =  get_user(request)
            except:
                author = 'Guest'
            d.title = form.cleaned_data['title'] 
            d.body = form.cleaned_data['body'] 
            d.published = False
            d.save()
```

The model which is used to generates form is:

```
class SendLetter(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    published = models.BooleanField(default= False, blank=True)
```

The form:

```
class SendLetterForm(forms.ModelForm):    
           class Meta():
        model = SendLetter
        exclude = ('author','created', 'published')
```

The table collation is set to `utf8mb4_bin` and the text is in Persian. I have also tried other utf8 collations like `utf8_persian_cli` without success. I‌ have no issues saving Persian text without smilies.

When I insert text containing smilies directly into the table field, using PhpMyAdmin, the smilies are  stored correctly.

I have also tried  d.body=form['body'] (without `cleaned_data`) but got the same `????` after save.

So the question is how can I save smilies correctly without compromising the form security?

Comment: [Check if this answers your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522102/django-mysql-arabic-encoding)

Comment: which db do you use?

Comment: MariaDB. using `utf8_unicode_ci `  collation for the field.

Comment: @Bijoy, I'm already using `utf8` adn `utf8_general_ci` in the db.

Comment: Did you try `utf8mb4` encoding ?

Comment: I changed `body` field collaction to `utf8mb4_bin` and also `utf8mb4_general_ci`  but still got the same problem.

Comment: Removed [tag:sql-injection] tag, because this question has nothing to do with SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15234369/7937129) adding

```
'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'},
```

tto the settings.py DATABASE options and setting the fields collation to `utf8mb4` solved the problem.